# OptaPlanner: Is the "constraint match" associated with a score just a semantical thing?

Tags: optaplanner

I have a question about OptaPlanner constraint stream API. Are the constraint matches only used to calculate the total score and are meant to help the user see how the score results, or is this information used to find a better solution?

With "used to find a better solution" I mean the information is used to get the next move(s) in the local search phase.

So does it matter which planning entity I penalize?

Currently, I am working on an examination scheduler. One requirement is to distribute the exams of a single student optimally.
The number of exams per student varies. Therefore, I wrote a cost function that gives a normalized value, indicating how well the student's exams are distributed.

Let's say the examination schedule in the picture has costs of 80. Now, I need to break down this value to the individual exams. There are two different ways to do this:

- Option A:  Penalize each of the exams with 10 (10*8 = 80).
- Option B: Penalize each exam according to its actual impact.=> Only the exams in the last week are penalized as the distribution of exams in week one and week two is fine.

Obviously, option B is semantically correct. But does the choice of the option affect the solving process?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constraint matches are there to help explain the score to humans. They do not, in any way, affect how the solver moves or what solution you are going to get. In fact, `ScoreManager` has the capability to calculate constraint matches after the solver has already finished, or for a solution that's never even been through the solver before.

(Note: constraint matching does affect performance, though. They slow everything down, due to all the object iteration and creation.)

To your second question: Yes, it does matter which entity you penalize. In fact, you want to penalize every entity that breaks your constraints. Ideally it should be penalized more, if it breaks the constraints more than some other entity - this way, you get to avoid score traps.

EDIT based on an edit to the question:

In this case, since you want to achieve fairness per student, I suggest your constraint does not penalize the exam, but rather the student. Per student, group your exams and apply some fairness `ConstraintCollector`. If you do it like that, you will be able to create a per-student fairness function and use its value as your penalty.

The [OptaPlanner Tennis example](https://docs.optaplanner.org/8.6.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#tennis) shows one way of doing fairness. You may also be interested in a [larger fairness discussion](https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2017/02/03/FormulaForMeasuringUnfairness.html) on the [OptaPlanner blog](https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added an example for my second question.